# how to check connectivity between a specfic neighbor of a node to all other neighbors without using node itself

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am developing a network protocol In which I have following requirement 
each node have information only about its neighbor. one of neighbor(j) of node i want to check if it can reach all other neighbors of node i without using node i. (if possible path should not be more than k links).
please suggest me if you have any idea to solve this problem
thanks.

Comment: I guess you want something better then the trivial "delete `i` and run BFS from `j`" ? Or is it a good solution for you? If not - what complexity are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't store anything but a node's neighbor, it sounds like you will need to run a [routing protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol) whenever the node needs to perform this check (and then throw away the results), like [RIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol).    With RIP you could poison the immediate path to i.  You can then examine the routing table to determine what paths are available (those that have less than k links).  There are many more protocols to choose from, but RIP has the benefit of being straightforward and has little overhead vs something like OSPF.

Comment: I *think* RIP will be very vulnerable to [count to infinity problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_to_infinity#Count-to-infinity_problem) in this scenerio, since we are invoking its trigger [deleing node `i`] many times... If you think I am wrong [it is very possible] or have a solution to this issue - please elaborate on it, I'd love to read it, since I was also thinking RIP and could not figure out a solution to this issue.

Comment: The fact that node i is unreachable through j should propagate to all nodes.  Thereby they will have to reevaluate their best route, if they were using the path ij.  I don't think that this would be an issue with the loop prevention mechanisms already built into RIP - poison reverse, split horizon, etc.